# Create a property inside an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an optional parameter and I simply want to create a property in runtime.
I wanted to avoid doing `data.assets = {}` and then assign the name.

Isn't there a simplier way to do this `data.assets.name = 'John';` if the `data.assets` do not exist?

```js
// Typescript
export interface Data {
  assets?: {
    name: string
  }
}

const data = {foo: 'bar'};
data.assets.name = 'John';

// Javascript generated code
const data = {foo: 'bar'};
data.assets.name = 'John'; // error here because assets is undefined
console.log(data);
```

Comment: If `data.assets = {name: "John"}` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wy676w) isn't sufficient, could you [edit] your question to clarify that?

Comment: `data.assets?.name = 'John'` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't avoid assing, you should the `assets` is some way after all

---

You may use the thing used by namespaces
Basically before you use a prop you assign it if it does not exist

```
((MyNamespace) => {
   MyNamespace.exported = 123
})(window.MyNamespace ??= {})
```

as

```
(data.assets ??= {}).assets.name = 'John';
```

---

```js
// Typescript
export interface Data {
  assets?: {
    name: string
  }
}

const data = {foo: 'bar'};
(data.assets ??= {}).name = 'John';

// Javascript generated code
const data = {foo: 'bar'};
data.assets.name = 'John'; // error here because assets is undefined
console.log(data);
```